# checking if a method is called using ASM

Tags: java, bytecode

I am working on a deobfuscator for an application which is heavily obfuscated. There are a lot of redundant methods which I would like to remove to simplify the code. Unfortunately, I don't have enough knowledge with asm and bytecode to be able to do this, could someone please enlighten me on how I would use asm to check for methods that are called?

Comment: Your answer is obvious: get more knowledge about ASM and bytecode. Both have [documentation](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf) [available](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html). Decompiling the application (or any Java code) with `javap -c` and poking through the output of that should also be helpful.

Comment: It's probably impossible to detect if a method is ever called or not if the application uses reflection to call those methods.

Comment: It doesn't use reflection, I know that much.

Comment: Have you tried using Krakatau? It's pretty good for deobfuscation. Unfortunately, it's not well documented, but if you have any questions you can always ask me.

Comment: Ah you're the same guy from yesterday :P
I would use Krakatau BUT that goes against the purpose of me making a deobfuscator..

Comment: Ok, if you want to do it yourself, feel free to go ahead. I was just trying to help.

Comment: I'm not saying that it doesn't help, but it's just that I don't want to rely on other peoples work, I want to use my own

Answer (score 1):

Gathering a list of methods that are called by a class is straightforward. If you are using the ASM sax api then just override

```
public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc)
```

And collect the method name, owners and signatures.

If you use the tree api the same information will be available from the MethodInsnNodes.

Generating a list of methods a class declares/defines is similarly straight forward - each one will result to a call to visitMethod or a method node in the tree api.